# Custom Panel not vertically scrolling

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a custom panel that allows users to arrange controls as they see fit.  This seems to be working expect that I can't get vertical scrolling to work.  I have tried setting the height of my panel, using the scrollviewer etc. Horizontal scrolling works like a charm.

Could you please help me figure out what I am missing.  I am wondering if it is a templating issue or something of the sort.  The SignalLayoutPanel is the panel that I would like to scroll.

Main window xaml:

```
<dock:DockingManager x:Name="Dock1" Grid.Row="1" 
                     AllowMixedOrientation="True"
                         DocumentsSource="{Binding Path=VisibleDockWindows}"
                         AnchorablesSource="{Binding Path=Tools}"
                         ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ActiveDocumentConverter}}"

                     >
        <dock:DockingManager.Theme>
            <dock:AeroTheme/>
        </dock:DockingManager.Theme>
        <dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector><!--Section determines which View is used-->
            <pane:PanesTemplateSelector>
                <pane:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SignalWindow AllowDrop="True" Background="LightGray" Height="Auto"/> <!--Panel not scrolling-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </pane:PanesTemplateSelector.FileViewTemplate>
                <pane:PanesTemplateSelector.SignalExplorerViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SignalExplorerTree/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </pane:PanesTemplateSelector.SignalExplorerViewTemplate>
                <pane:PanesTemplateSelector.PanelExplorerViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:PanelExplorerWindow/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </pane:PanesTemplateSelector.PanelExplorerViewTemplate>
                <pane:PanesTemplateSelector.PropertiesViewTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:PropertyViewer1/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </pane:PanesTemplateSelector.PropertiesViewTemplate>
            </pane:PanesTemplateSelector>
        </dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
        <dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
            <pane:PanesStyleSelector>
                <pane:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dock:LayoutAnchorableItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}, Converter={StaticResource btvc}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentID}"/>
                    </Style>
                </pane:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
                <pane:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dock:LayoutItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentID}"/>
                    </Style>
                </pane:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
            </pane:PanesStyleSelector>
        </dock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
</dock:DockingManager>
```

SignalWindow.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ControllerInterfaceWithExplorer2.SignalWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ControllerInterfaceWithExplorer2"
         xmlns:lv ="clr-namespace:ControllerInterfaceWithExplorer2.View"
         xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:ControllerInterfaceWithExplorer2.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
         AllowDrop="True">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <VM:SignalTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DID">
        <local:SignalViewer/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RID">
        <local:RoutineViewer/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IO">
        <local:IOViewer/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Grid.Row="0" Height="80">
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Signals}"  
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >

                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <!--Panel that won't scroll vertically-->
                    <lv:SignalLayoutPanel Height="Auto" AllowDrop="True" />

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <!--<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Read" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Write" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>-->
    <!--<DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel" MouseDown="dockPanel_MouseDown" MouseMove="dockPanel_MouseMove" MouseUp="dockPanel_MouseUp">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Read" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Write" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Height="150" Width="Auto">
        <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Signals}"  
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}" MouseDown="dockPanel_MouseDown">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <lv:SignalLayoutPanel AllowDrop="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>-->


</Grid>
```

SignalLayoutPanel.cs:

```
 public class SignalLayoutPanel:Panel
{
    public SignalLayoutPanel()
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Chartreuse;
        this.MouseMove += SignalLayoutPanel_MouseMove;
        this.MouseEnter += SignalLayoutPanel_MouseEnter;
        this.MouseLeave += SignalLayoutPanel_MouseLeave;
        this.DragEnter += SignalLayoutPanel_DragEnter;
        this.MouseDown += SignalLayoutPanel_MouseDown;
        this.MouseUp += SignalLayoutPanel_MouseUp;
        this.Drop += SignalLayoutPanel_Drop;
        this.SourceUpdated += SignalLayoutPanel_SourceUpdated;
        this.TargetUpdated += SignalLayoutPanel_TargetUpdated;

    }


    private void SignalLayoutPanel_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentControl = null;
        InvalidateArrange();
    }

    private StackPanel _currentControl;

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, e.GetPosition(this));
        _currentControl = GetCurrentStackPanel(result);
    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_TargetUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_SourceUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ViewModel.SignalViewModel));
        if (data != null)
        {
            ViewModel.SignalViewModel vm = data as ViewModel.SignalViewModel;
            ViewModel.SignalWindowViewModel svw = this.DataContext as ViewModel.SignalWindowViewModel;
            if (vm.Model.GetType() == typeof(DataModel.DIDClass))
            {
                double tempX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
                double tempY = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
                foreach (ViewModel.SignalViewModel signalView in vm.Children)
                {
                    signalView.PositionX = tempX;
                    signalView.PositionY = tempY;
                    //Signals.Add(signalView);
                    svw.Add(signalView);
                    tempY += 40;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                vm.PositionX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
                vm.PositionY = e.GetPosition(this).Y;


                svw.Add(vm);
            }


        }

    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ViewModel.SignalViewModel));
        //get signal
        if (data != null)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SignalLayoutPanel_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed && _currentControl != null)
        {
            if(_currentControl.DataContext is ViewModel.SignalViewModel)
            {
                ViewModel.SignalViewModel svm = _currentControl.DataContext as ViewModel.SignalViewModel;
                svm.PositionX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
                svm.PositionY = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size idealSize = new Size(0, 0);

        // Allow children as much room as they want - then scale them
        Size size = new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity);
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(size);
            idealSize.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            idealSize.Height = 20;// Math.Max(idealSize.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }

        // EID calls us with infinity, but framework doesn't like us to return infinity
        if (double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Height) || double.IsInfinity(availableSize.Width))
            return idealSize;
        else
            return availableSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        //double x = 5;
        //double y = 5;

        //for(int i=0; i < InternalChildren.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    InternalChildren[i].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), InternalChildren[i].DesiredSize));
        //    y += InternalChildren[i].DesiredSize.Height;


        //}
        foreach(UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
           if( ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)child).DataContext  is ViewModel.SignalViewModel)
            {
                ViewModel.SignalViewModel svm = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)child).DataContext as ViewModel.SignalViewModel;
                child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(svm.PositionX, svm.PositionY), child.DesiredSize));
            }
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    private StackPanel GetCurrentStackPanel(HitTestResult hitTest)
    {
        StackPanel retVal = null;
        var element = hitTest.VisualHit as FrameworkElement;
        FrameworkElement temp = element;
        while (temp != null && !(temp is StackPanel))
            if (temp != null)
                temp = temp.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        if (temp != null)
            retVal = temp as StackPanel;
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: What size does your MeasureOverride return at the end? I don't remember the details, but the last time I had to implement a custom panel it required implementing the IScrollInfo interface, so that the size being passed to MeasureOverride is the viewport size of the ScrollViewer. This interface, however, is very bulky and tedious to implement ...

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you are setting _currentControl = null in the MouseUp handler, i.e. assuming that after each MouseDown there must be a MouseUp event. The problem is that the mouse device is not entirely under your control and the OS or some other app can capture the mouse (google mouse capture API) at any time and you won't get a matching MouseUp event. This is solved by handling the LostMouseCapture event.

Comment: shadow32  - thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  When calculating the idealsize I wasn't incrementing the height; just setting it to a fixed value of 20.  Incrementing this caused the scrollbar to function as expected.

Also thank you for the tip on the mouse events; good info!